# Conditional Required Field Validators

Tags: asp.net, validation-controls

I have all fields set to required using the requiredfield control in asp.net but i need one field to change its requiredfield control to disabled depending on a radio button answer. Is there a way to do this without using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

On the radiobutton selection (OnChecked_Changed) event do the setting

```
if(radiobutton.Checked)
{
   requiredFieldValidatorID.Enabled = false; 
}
else
{
    requirefFieldValidatorID.Enabled = true;
}
```

Be sure you use validationGroup, Then on the Submit of the page call that.

```
 Page.Validate("validationGroupName");
```

Then check is page valid to continue e.g.

```
//call page validation 
Page.Validate("validationGroupName");
if(Page.IsValid)
{
// process here 
}
```